# how do you extract the root directory?

Tags: php, directory-structure

I am still learning php.

```
'SCRIPT_FILENAME' => string 'D:/Project Storage/wnmp/www/folder/index.php' (length=45)
'SCRIPT_NAME'     => string '/folder/index.php' (length=18)
'DOCUMENT_URI'    => string '/folder/index.php' (length=18)
'PHP_SELF'        => string '/folder/index.php' (length=18)
'REQUEST_URI'     => string '/folder/helloworld/helloworldtwo/etc' (length=15)
```

as you can see i just want to get the `helloworld/helloworldtwo/etc`

any idea to **extract the folder** ? so it will be `helloworld/helloworldtwo/etc` ?

what im thinking is im defining my folder like `$root = 'folder'`. then i extract it if it match, but the problem is with what ?

the second idea is to get from php_self or anything above to get the first from /first/second.php,
but again i dont know the best way to do it.

and another problem is when we have like two folders in the front ? btw thanks for all of the replay, im still doing some read php.net, test, and try.

```
'SCRIPT_FILENAME' => string 'D:/Project Storage/wnmp/www/folder/index.php' (length=45)
'SCRIPT_NAME'     => string '/folder/folder2/index.php' (length=18)
'DOCUMENT_URI'    => string '/folder/folder2/index.php' (length=18)
'PHP_SELF'        => string '/folder/folder2/index.php' (length=18)
'REQUEST_URI'     => string '/folder/folder2/helloworld/helloworldtwo/etc' (length=15)
```

the question is still the same how can i get the helloworld/hellowrodltwo/etc the right way.

edit*
guys thanks a lot i have made a solution

```
$str = 'folder/folder/helloworld/helloworldtwo/etc';
$folder = 'folder/folder';
$q = str_replace($folder, NULL, $str);
echo $q;
```

but if there is anything / alternative or a better way to do it please do.

Thanks again.

Comment: Have you looked at [parse_url](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) and [pathinfo](http://uk3.php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php) - and their associated functions (like basename, etc.)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the explode function in PHP

```
$str = 'folder/helloworld/helloworldtwo/etc';

print_r(explode('/', $str, 2));
```

The output will be:

```
Array
(
    [0] => folder
    [1] => helloworld/helloworldtwo/etc
)
```

If you have multiple folder/ you can do use 'folder/' as the delimiter and don't impose a limit

```
$str = 'folder/folder/helloworld/helloworldtwo/etc';

print_r(explode('folder/', $str));
```

The output will be:

```
array (
  0 => '',
  1 => '',
  2 => 'helloworld/helloworldtwo/etc',
)
```

then you can use the implode function to join it back into a string

```
$returnValue = implode('', array (
  0 => '',
  1 => '',
  2 => 'helloworld/helloworldtwo/etc',
));
```

Joining this 2 functions you can remove how many folders you want from the url and have the clean url at the end in a string

Answer (score 1):

If you know that it will always be `"/folder/"` that you want removed then you can use something like:

```
$extracted = str_replace("/folder/","",$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],1);
```

What this doest it replaces all occurences of `/folder/` with and empty string. This will give problems with urls such as `/folder/helloworld/folder/helloworld2`

Comment: Important note that the slashes should always be within the string otherwise may cause problems.